# I can not open csv file in R

Tags: r, csv, export-to-csv

This is my csv file seperated with ","

[image]

when I try to open this file into R with this code

```
idt <- read.csv(file="C:/Users/R&K&T&E/Desktop/idtbest/idtbest2.csv",    
                header =TRUE , sep=",")
```

I see a duplicate row.names error 
when I tried `row.names=NULL` this happened

[image]

but my purpose is getting this shape

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try either

```
idf <- read.csv(file="C:/Users/R&K&T&E/Desktop/idtbest/idtbest2.csv")
```

or

```
idf <- read_csv(file="C:/Users/R&K&T&E/Desktop/idtbest/idtbest2.csv")
```

The former is from the *base* package and the latter from  *readr*.
In both cases, there is no need to specify the value for the arguments *header* and *sep* as they are set to *TRUE* and *","* by default respectively.

However, you should use the functions *read.csv2* or *read_csv2* if the field separator character for your csv file is ";".

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you can do `sep=";"`